# How do I create a backup OpenLDAP server?

Tags: openldap, debian-etch, master-slave

I have an OpenLDAP server running on a Debian machine that serves logins to various machines. I would like to create a backup server, which simply keeps a copy of all the OpenLDAP data so that in case the original server fails, the backup server can start serving logins once its IP is changed to that of the original server and the OpenLDAP server is started on it.

How can this be done? Or is it recommended to create a slave OpenLDAP server? If I create a slave server, will all the client machines that have already been configured (over 40 of them) need extra configuration to know about the slave server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is with a slave openldap server. The slave setup in openldap has completly changed between the current version (2.4) and previous versions. On etch, you'll probably need to look for older documentation or consider upgrading.

Although IP failover is an option as you suggested I would recommend configuring all the machines to use both servers.